# How to remove elements from the spacemacs mode-line

Tags: mode-line, spacemacs

I'd like to remove certain elements from the mode-line:
[image: modeline]

To the left, the `802` is the buffer size in bytes, if I'm not mistaken. I could not care less about that.

To the right, it tells me the buffer uses unix linebreaks, and I have no idea what the `2.2.3` is, but it doesn't go away when toggling the "new version" element via `SPC t m V`.

I'd also like to remove the rightmost buffer progress indicator, and replace it with an `x/y` element in the point position field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Spacemacs mode-line is provided by the [Spaceline](https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline) package.
The answer for your question is found in the README, under the [Turning segments on and off](https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline#turning-segments-on-and-off) section.

To toggle off the buffer size, add this to your init file:

```
(spaceline-toggle-buffer-size-off)
```

I'm not sure what displays the `2.2.3`, though it might be from the `perspective.el` package. If it's not, there's also a list of all segments under the same section, so you can try them one by one until it works. Then you add the correct `(spaceline-toggle-<segment-name>-off)` to your mode-line.

About replacing a segment, I'm not sure what's the best way. You probably need to remove the segment and define your own segment via `spaceline-define-segment`, which is also explained in the README.
To add your segment to the mode-line, the README says to use `spaceline-install`, but it requires you to specify the entire mode-line specification. If that's not what you want, you can try modifying the variables `spaceline-left` and `spaceline-right`, which are lists of mode-line segments. See their documentation for more (`C-h v <variable-name>`).

Answer (score 0):

my humble guess is your `2.2.3` is your ruby version. you can remove it by removing the following variable in your `.spacemacs` file.

```
(defun dotspacemacs-configuration-layers ()
   '((ruby :variables ruby-version-manager 'rvm)))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon Yuan Gao is correct. The [2.2.3] is your ruby version. Most likely from this package https://github.com/senny/rbenv.el

If you are using this package then M-x and type global-rbenv-mode to toggle it on and off.

To permanently this off, add the following to your .emacs file:
(global-rbenv-mode -1)

This worked for me.